# Tips on storing Query values and passing them between activities?

Tags: java, android, json

I trying to store a list of songs that I query from Android Media Store but I am not sure how to save multiple columns (i.e. song name, track path, duration, etc..)

I currently use a HashMap and ArrayList to display the song Name and Duration in a list view but I'd like to store more information from my query. Any tips on how to get a multidimensional vector/container of some sort? I tried using JSON obj/arrays but I everytime I store values in them I can only get that last one out...

```
while (c.moveToNext()) {

                HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();

                temp.put("Title", c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                temp.put("Duration", Tools.stringOfTime(Long.parseLong(c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION)))));
                list.add(temp);
```

JSON attempt... basically I added each query row into 1 json object and kept putting those objects into a json array but for some reason I can only get the last value from my list where as the hashmap approach works fine but can only store 2 fields..

```
// object = new JSONObject();
                // try {
                // object.put(
                // "Title",
                // c.getString(c
                // .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                // object.put("Data", c.getString(c
                // .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)));
                // object.put("Artist", c.getString(c
                // .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)));
                // object.put("Album", c.getString(c
                // .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)));
                // object.put("Duration", c.getString(c
                // .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION)));
                // jarray.put(object);
                // } catch (JSONException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                // }
                //
                // jlist.add(object);
                // }
                // try {
                // tv.setText(object.getString("Title"));
                // } catch (JSONException e) {
                // // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                // e.printStackTrace();
                // Log.d("SongsActivity", "Couldn't print json object");
                // }
```

Comment: What's wrong with using the cursor since all the data is already there?  If you need it in another activity, just run the query again.

Comment: Thanks I figured what to do actually. I wanted to have my user click certain query results and then I would use them to make a play list.

Answer (score 0):

Store the cursor object in an Application class field variable.

Like: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: Thanks but to be honest... I don' really know what this means, I'm kind of an android newb but I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0):

Did some quick research, and almost every answer I see to questions like this returns to:  run the query again in the next activity.

The other answer was to create an application class to act as a data hub.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i figured out what to do